# piping command output to text files not working

Tags: windows-7, command-line, cmd.exe

Trying to use CMD to print the output of an executable to a file. The name of the program is adb (in my path). When called without arguments it prints the help text. I can't seem to capture it.

`adb > adb.txt` - Doesn't work, get an empty txt file
`dir > adb.txt` - Works fine

I'm probably not seeing something obvious.

Comment: so `adb>a ` still dumps the output of adb, you want `adb 2>a`

Comment: notice that dir sfdsff  so as to give a file not found, will need 2>a too.

Comment: @barlop thanks, maybe I'll see if I can tweak my console to change colors depending on stderr or stdout :)

Comment: I can't imagine any option within cmd itself. There is a color command but to link it to stdout and stderr, I doubt..  so maybe http://www.nextofwindows.com/4-better-windows-console-tools-alternatives-to-windows-built-in-command-prompt    though even there I doubt it, though I haven't really used the alternatives much, but it'd be a damn good feature if it was there.

Comment: @barlop actually I'm using conemu64. Doesn't feel as fast sometimes, but supports full screen and normal copy pasting. Lots of options I still need to browse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a fault with piping (This is actually redirection, piping uses the output in the command of another program, using the | operator), but how `adb` has implemented output to the cmd prompt. Instead of outputting to STDOUT, it outputs this text to STDERR.

Try this command instead:

`adb 2>adb.txt`

More information [here](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true)

Comment: thanks, odd that it uses stderr for those kind of messages.

Comment: @jiggunjer Sort of, except it actually *is* an error message as you've called it without parameters, just not a very concise one ;)

Comment: Actually it does the same with `adb -h`, which is the help switch.